# Error occuring in that line no. which doesn't present in code

Tags: javascript

When i am running the javascript code that is reading excel of 237 rows so it runs well but when i am reading the excel of 999 rows with the same code so it gives error "Number expected" in line 272 although my code ends at line 268.Can anyone plz tell me how to fix it

Comment: could you provide your JavaScript and/or excel file?

Answer (score 1):

Load your page in IE8 and change the options to allow debugging - this will let you jump straight to the error code.

Comment: If you're willing to install IE9 beta, it provides even better debugging/diagnostic abilities (break on errors!)

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening in ie < 9 pehaps your error is in another js file that is included in your page (ie < 9 does not tell you which file the error is in)

Comment: No, i am not using any file in javascript code,i can't understand that its not showing any error when reading 237 rows excel but for reading 99 rows excel its showing error even i didn't do any change in code

Comment: Script debugger is showing error in the unknown code in different language,not in my code.What should i do now????